# if else statement not work in option input

Tags: php

HERE is my code :

```
var $myarray =array ('black','blue','brown','yellow')

if ( $row['color']=="") {
    echo"<option value='' selected>---select---</option>";
}

foreach ($myarray as $color) {

    if ($row['color']!="" && $row['color']==$color) {

        echo"<option value='$color' selected>$color</option>";

    }else {
        echo"<option value='$color'>$color</option>";
    }

}
```

**My question is** how to get rid of the (<`option value='' selected>---select---</option>)`
if $row['color'] is not null or not empty?

I´ve tried many ways...but nothing helped. :S

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: No not error, but i just want to get rid the first empty option if the row is not null.

Comment: There is no way you didn't get any errors. I'm counting 4 syntax errors already.

Comment: You should only control `selected="selected"` part. No need to `echo` out entire `<option ...>` section.

Comment: @ programminginallston I haven´t copy from the original because of too much code there. Here is a small version of it. And in my original it does not show any error. But I have fexed the code above.

Comment: @u54r  What did you mean ? or how to do it ?

Comment: You're trying to control only `selected` section. It is redundant and inefficient to re-write the code as you're doing  it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$myarray =array ('black','blue','brown','yellow');
$row['color']='';
?>
<select name='whatever'>

<?php
    if ($row['color']=='' || $row['color']==null){
       echo "<option value=''>----Select----</option>";
    }
    foreach ($myarray as $color){

        if ($row['color']==$color){
            echo"<option value='$color' selected>$color</option>";
        }
        else{
            echo"<option value='$color'>$color</option>";
        }
     }
 ?>
```

Comment: I have tried it...but it does not remove the <option value=''>----Select----</option>

When the $row['color'] is not empty :S

Comment: so what you want is to completely remove the ---select---option if the value for $row['color'] exists?

Comment: -dishwasherWithProgrammingSkill yes ....you understand me now
Because when  the value for $row['color'] exists i don´t need people to see the ---select----option anymore....it will show only first time when people have not choose yet...After that they can only change colur...

Comment: yup! give me a few minute

Comment: Here you go, I think this is what you were looking for. Your posted contents were logically correct but had few syntax errors. I tested it and it works as you wanted. When the row['color'] is empty it will display the ---select---option and if not then the option will not be parsed.

Comment: Where is the code you´re talking about ? which one I have to try now ?

Comment: I hve tested it, it´s not work until i remove $row['color']='';  and when I remove it and the $row['color'] is not empty the ----select----still be there althogh everything´s working.

Comment: I finally got it !!!
The reason I does´nt work in the beginning is because I did not put the $row['color']=''; on the most top of document (Because in the original file I have too many thing there..And the database query was placed above the $row['color']='') that´s why it did not work :)

But After I put it into the most top of the document,, the ---select---is completely not show up any more !

<3 thank for help !!

Answer (score 0):

You declared the variable in the first line with `var`, which is not a part of PHP.  You need to declare it like all your other variables, by putting a `$` at the start of it.  You also reference `$mysrray` instead of `$myarray`

Comment: But how can I remove the first blank option if the $row['color'] is not empty ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. it should work.

```
$myarray = array('black','blue','brown','yellow')

foreach ($myarray as $color) {

 if ($row['color'] != "" && $row['color']==$color)
 {
    echo '<option value="'.$color.'" selected="selected">'.$color.'</option>';
 }
 elseif($row['color']=="")
 {
    echo '<option value="" selected="selected">---select---</option>';
 }
}
```

Comment: This will not work. you have logical errors on the if-else statement.

Comment: I have tried it but it show only <option value="" selected="selected">---select---</option> :S